# Is there a word for someone who has been in power for an unusually long period of time?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whether democratically elected or not, some people are in power [for unusually long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_longest-ruling_non-royal_national_leaders). What word distinguishes for example, a democratically elected official who has been in power for 40 years versus one that's been in power for 2 years?

You might think such a word is inappropriate because there's no clear place to draw the line where "unusually long" starts, but in baseball we do have the term "veteran player" to describe a player that has many seasons of experience. 
In this context "veteran" usually has a positive connotation.

The term "veteran president" or "veteran dictator" doesn't seem right because "veteran" has a positive connotation (meaning "well experienced"), whereas for unusually long or dangerously long terms in office one might want to use a word that puts emphasis not on the benefit of having a lot of experience, but maybe on the drawbacks of being in power for such a long time.

Comment: There are, of course, **monarchs**, who serve for life by definition. (You started your question with "whether democratically elected or not," but then seemed to change what you were looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

**long-running** [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/long-running)

> having continued for a long time / of considerable duration

and/or

**long-standing**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/long-standing)

> existing or in effect for a long time

Comment: Would it not be 'long-standing' ? 'Running' for President means 'not yet elected'.

Comment: @NigelJ noted and so edited

Answer (score 0):

**president-for-life**

> A person with lifetime tenure as the head of a government or organization

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/president-for-life)